# How to make a digit round?

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I want `3000` for all these numbers:

```
3001 - 3500 - 3999
```

I want `40000` for all these numbers:

```
40000.3 - 40101 - 48000.8 - 49901
```

I want `20` for all these numbers:

```
21 - 25.2 - 29
```

---

There is two PHP function to make a digit round *([floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) and [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php))* But none of them [don't act exactly what I need](https://3v4l.org/XNULZ).

**Note:** I don't know my number is contains how many digits. If fact it is changing.

Is there any approach to do that?

Comment: Easiest way in my mind, count the strlen (string length), and then take the first number and ensure via the string length count, that it gets the correct amount of 0's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are "many" ways how to achieve this. One is this:

```
<?php

echo roundNumber( 29 )."<br>";
echo roundNumber( 590 )."<br>";
echo roundNumber( 3670 )."<br>";
echo roundNumber( 49589 )."<br>";

function roundNumber( $number )
{
    $digitCount = floor( log10( $number ) ) ;
    $base10     = pow( 10, $digitCount );
    return floor( $number /  $base10 ) * $base10;
}
?>
```

The output is this:

```
20
500
3000
40000
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any no. of digits. Try this:

```
$input = 25.45;

if (strpos($input, ".") !== FALSE) {
    $num = explode('.', $input);
    $len = strlen($num[0]);
    $input = $num[0];
} else {
    $len = strlen($input);
}

$nearest_zeroes = str_repeat("0", $len-1);

$nearest_round = '1'.$nearest_zeroes;

echo floor($input/$nearest_round) * $nearest_round;
```

The idea is when you round a 4 digit no, say 3999, $nearest_round should be 1000.

For 39990(5 digit), $nearest_round = 10000.

For 25(2 digit),  $nearest_round = 10.

And so on.

So, the idea is to generate  $nearest_round dynamically based on the no. of digits of $input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've made the necessary changes for decimal input. Please take a look.